# React image gallery

Tags: reactjs, arrays, image-gallery

sorry for the probably easy question, I'm just starting with react, etc. and I want to make an image array, a gallery where I would retrieve the images from the folder. The folder is now under the src folder and I have tried many ways without success. Could someone tell me whether the image folder should be under public or src and how to mark the array blocks / retrieve the images correctly? I can't find instructions for working with local folder / images anywhere..

for example

```
 const images = [{id: 1, imageURL: require('./img/i1.jpg')}]
```

and const images = [{id: 1, }] etc,.

Answer (score 0):

folder should be under public and you can use img like this

```html
<img src='/img-folder/logo192.png' alt='ss'/>
```

```html
 const images = [{id: 1, imageURL: require('/img-folder/logo192.png')}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the instructions Arash! unfortunately the problem is still there, the images retrieved from the internet are displayed ok and the browser does not give error messages, but the images in the public folder are not displayed. Just white. I'm trying to figure out :  /

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: https://github.com/webstylepress/React-JS-Image-Gallery/tree/main/src
the code is not mine, I copied it from wsp (full respect!) and I'm experimenting with it, trying to find ways to do certain things etc. basically it's the same as the original code but the images are in the Public folder ..